# How to insert the same element on beginning and on the end of the list with insertBefore and appendChild?

Tags: javascript, dom, appendchild

I would like to add **elements** with the **same text** on the end and at the beginning of the list. I want use `appendChild` and `insertBefore`. But, if I do this in following way is added only one element, this which is as last in the code of the script:

```js
var list = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
var firstElement = list.firstChild;
var newElement = document.createElement('li');
var newText = document.createTextNode('new text');
newElement.appendChild(newText);

list.appendChild(newElement);
list.insertBefore(newElement, firstElement);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to clone the element you want to insert. 
In your code you are *"moving"* the element from the button to the top, because you dealing with the same item which can only exist once in the html.

So just add a `.cloneNode(true)` and a cloned item can be at the top and at the other one at the bottom.

```js
var list = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
var firstElement = list.firstChild;
var newElement = document.createElement('li');
var newText = document.createTextNode('new text');
newElement.appendChild(newText);

list.appendChild(newElement);
list.insertBefore(newElement.cloneNode(true), firstElement);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```